# Viewer search with attributeNames from an IFC file

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Searching with viewer.search() and using attributeNames when using an file converted from an IFC file, the attributeNames are too general. Instead of attributeName being for example IfcDescription almost all IFC attributeNames are LcIFCProperty:IFCString.

Can I use displayCategory, displayName or displayValue to narrow down the search? Or is there any plans to make more specific attributeNames in the future?

```
attributeName:"LcIFCProperty:IFCString"
displayCategory:"IFC"
displayName:"DESCRIPTION"
displayValue:"Supply air device"
```

These are two different properties, both have LcIFCProperty:IFCString as the attributeName.

```
attributeName:"LcIFCProperty:IFCString"
displayCategory:"MagiCAD Pset_AirTerminal"
displayName:"PartType"
displayValue:"Supply air device"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct, the viewer.search() method will restrict the search to attribute specified on the [attributeNames array](http://search(text,onSuccessCallback,onErrorCallback,attributeNames)). If you want to search everywhere, just use null instead.

As per [2.11 version change log](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/overview/changelog/2.11/): *viewer.getProperties() will now return both attributeName and displayName (if available). The attributeName can be use as a filter for viewer.search() calls.*